# How to filter all emails sent VIA domain.com

Tags: gmail-filters

I keep receiving spam mails from different senders using different domain names (e.g. newsletter@buyerkart.info via  utilityinbox.com).

I could create a filter to catch all mail from newsletter@buyerkart.info, but I want to catch/filter all the mail sent **via** utilityinbox.com.

How could I achieve that?

Edit: Screen shot attached.[image]

Comment: You are marking them as spam, no? That helps Google improve spam filters.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this string? Can you [edit] your question and add the headers of such a message? (Be sure to anonymize any personal information.)

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution to this for a while. From what I've gathered so far it's not currently possible in GMail.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out emails sent via a domain using a Google Apps Script.

The reason Gmail's built-in filters won't work in this situation is because they can't be applied to the "X-Forwarded-For" header. That header is where the "via" domain info is stored.

However, you could use a Google Apps Script to check your inbox every few minutes and automatically filter out messages sent via a specific domain. It actually works really well. Since implementing the script myself, I haven't had to deal with this type of spam at all. You can read my full walkthrough here: http://www.geektron.com/2014/01/how-to-filter-gmail-using-email-headers-and-stop-via-spam/

Answer (score 1):

utilityinbox.com works as an email server and provides mailing services to it's client. So it's different client's can send you marketing mails.

> Currently you cannot create a filter by yourself but marking it spam might help you and gmail as it's marks the ip address of the sender as spam rather than the email address. Even you can opt to remove yourself from that mailing list.

You only need go to [this link](http://utilityinbox.com/aboutus.html) and unsubscribe yourself...
**OR**
And the other alternate is according to [CAN-SPAM Act](http://www.business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business) there would be an unsubscribe link at the of the mail click on it and you are done.